# Adding associated records while updating a record rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, nested-attributes

```
 def upload_new_incident_attachments
    @attachments.each do |attachment|
        if record.new_record?
          record.images.build(attachment: attachment)
        else
          record.images.create(attachment: attachment)
        end
    end
end
```

Build the associated records will get automatically saved if the parent model gets created(while saving), The child attributes won't get saved  if there are validation errors(both in child and parent), I don't know how to handle this  while updating the parent model,

```
def update
   if record.update_attributes(incident_params)
     upload_new_record_attachments if @attachments
   end
end
```

If there are validation errors while creating the child record, the parent model updated already, Is there any way to update both in a single commit( create child record and updating parent record), Or any other ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if its parent model is valid before building or creating child associations

```
def update
  # Assign attributes to the parent model
  record.assign_attributes(incident_params)

  if record.valid?
    # Builds or creates images only when there are no validation errors
    upload_new_record_attachments if @attachments

    # Now you can save it and make sure there won't be any validation errors
    record.save
  end
end
```